# Does ASP.NET have the equivalent of VB's InputBox function?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inputbox

VB has a function InputBox() that will prompt the user to enter a single value, then click OK.

Is there a parallel functionality in ASP.NET, that will get the browser to pop up some kind of input box to return a single value?

If not, how do you recommend I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in JavaScript

```
var result = prompt("Question", "Default text");
document.getElementById("HiddenInputBox").value = result;
document.HiddenForm.submit();
```

But most web apps seem to use of screen forms and simulated modal dialogs (fade and disable rest of screen)

jQuery is your friend for this, try [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Answer (score 3):

For more functionality, check out the asp.net ajax control toolkit, and specifically the modal popup box control.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Yes - use the `prompt()` javascript function.

```
var x = prompt("enter a value");
```

Comment: You might want to provide an example of how he would access that value from the code-behind.